# Tx stuck on Ethereum Ropsten

Tags: mining, ropsten, txpool

Why my transaction is not mined on Ethereum Ropsten? https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x383b129d87cd6991df7701d3e4a018f8e3dd02d973aea5a8ea53ab5791146614

It shows up on https://ropsten.etherscan.io/txsPending?p=5 as stuck. Having `GasLimit` of 4700000   and GasPrice of 101 Gwei, why it is still not mined?

Comment: Now it is mined, but it took almost 1 day

Comment: From my experience it seems miners in ropsten do not like transactions with a large gas limit.